# Mongoose: What can I assume about my data in the event of an error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I'm doing a single-collection, multi-document operation through Mongoose such as

```
// all my_model doc's have flag==false here
my_model.update({flag:false}, {flag:true}, {multi:true}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
         // what can I assume here?
    }
});
```

What can I say about my `my_model` documents in the event of an error? Will some have `flag == true`? Or is it an atomic operation in the sense that if there is an error, none of the updates will occur?

Is this behavior consistent amongst other multi-document operations with a single collection (ex `remove()`) ? Is this the price I pay for non-ACIDity ?

**edit**: From the mongodb docs:

> The modification of a single document is always atomic, even if the write operation modifies multiple sub-documents within that document. For write operations that modify multiple documents, the operation as a whole is not atomic, and other operations may interleave.

Since other operations may interleave, I can only assume then that in the event of an error, the data would be in a transtional state, with some docs updated and others not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. If there is an error during a multi-document update, you may have a situation in which some of the documents have `flag == true` and others have `flag == false`.